# Stop rhubarb compote juice from leaking

Tags: baking, rhubarb

I am making a rhubarb meringue pie by first blind-baking a short pastry, afterwards I put the rhubarb-compote onto the cake and the meringue on top, and then bake that again for a short time.

However, after and while baking, the juice of the rhubarbs starts leaking en masse. What can I do to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 4):

Consider two options:

Add a stabilizing agent for the compote: cornstarch immediately comes to mind, but I suppose sewit, or custard would do the trick. This automatically lends itself to needing a longer bake time which I can understand to be less favorable.

Try reducing more moisture while prepping the compote. By giving the rhubarb a longer cooking time, you can also intensify its flavor while getting a firmer, stickier compote.

Answer (score 1):

To thicken the compote there are many ingredients you could turn to. Toss the rhubarb stocks with a couple of tbsps of flour before baking. The flour would absorb the juice that is released and thicken the compote. Cornstarch can do the same job as flour. But my personal favorite is quick cooking tapioca. I find this to be the most effective in 'drinking' up the juices of the rhubarb. I got the idea from [this blogpost by Smitten Kitchen](http://smittenkitchen.com/blog/2010/06/strawberry-rhubarb-pie-improved/) (no affiliation whatsoever).